# Use local time on the chat search results page

Tags: feature-request, chat, timezone

The search results page for chat lists times in UTC. My local timezone is BST and this is correct elsewhere in chat.

Since UTC is used for timestamps on SO proper, at the very least this is an inconsistency with the similarly-rendered timestamps in just chat.

We should be consistent in which timezone is used for timestamps across all chat pages.

Example: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=amitriptyline&room=10

Comment: I see correct UTC times there. It is UTC **everywhere on the site**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not in chat it isn't.

Comment: If times *in the chatroom* are in local time, then that's the exception. I don't think that the search results or transcripts are doing that though; they are all in UTC.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, that's what this question says. It's inconsistent or at least confusing, for as long as the timestamps are rendered in the same font, the same size and in the same location. A message recently posted contained a link to search results, of which the self-same message was itself one; it was very confusing that the time was an hour behind there.

Comment: Well, transcript URLs include the time slots. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10/2014/4/21/14-17 for example; you cannot have that *and* have local time in the transcript.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Why not? Make the time slots local time. All other chat clients work this way.

Comment: Then how do you propose this works when sharing a URL?

Comment: URLs don't need to be localised to show a properly localised UI.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To be honest I don't really care. What I care about is the resulting experience and, right now, it quite obviously violates PLS.

Comment: You could make the URL describe the ID of the first message to display, rather than a date and time range. The proper local time slot for display can be resolved from that ID. I really don't think the transcript time slot URL feature is more important than having individual timestamps that make sense across all of chat.

Comment: This isn't a bug - the behaviour (local time in chat rooms, UTC elsewhere) is by design. I've edited to make this a feature request instead, though no promises on implementation.

Comment: I completely concur. I often have a hard time to relate my search results to actual incidents/events in the Lounge. Call me date-challenged, but I rarely have a clue what the timestamp in chat search means

Comment: @Elastic Please don't use code formatting for not-code